# Symfony2 Twig and boolean false

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I try to generate URL with Twig in my Symfony2 project.
My URL take Boolean as parameters, when I put True in the twig it's work but when I put false an error is throw.

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Parameter "boolean" for route "route_1" must match "[^/]++" (""
>   given).

```
{{ path('route_1', {'id': item.id, 'boolean': false }) }}
```

I haven't any requirement on this parameter.

```
    /**
     * @Route("route1-{id}/boolean{boolean}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, name="route_1")
     */
    public function Route1Action($id, $boolean, Request $request) {
         //Some stuff
    }
```

---

**Edit**

So, use Boolean in URL is bad. I put number and php convert automatically in boolean. 0 is false and all other numbers is true.

```
<?php
var_dump((bool) "");        // bool(false)
var_dump((bool) 1);         // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) -2);        // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) "foo");     // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) 2.3e5);     // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) array(12)); // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) array());   // bool(false)
var_dump((bool) "false");   // bool(true)
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

With this code it's work :

Action :

```
/**
 * @Route("route1-{id}/boolean{boolean}", requirements={"id" = "\d+", "boolean" = "\d+"}, name="route_1")
 */
public function Route1Action($id, $boolean, Request $request) {
     //Some stuff
}
```

The url to generate :

```
{{ path('route_1', {'id': item.id, 'boolean': 0 }) }} //To send false
{{ path('route_1', {'id': item.id, 'boolean': 1 }) }} //To send true (1 or any other numbers)
```

**Thanks for your help. :)**

Comment: Please show your action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It kind of depends on what exactly you want to have in the URL. Boolean variables are generally not a good idea, since URL is a string.

Will the boolean variable be represented as `true` or as `1` ?

```
{{ path('route_1', {'id': item.id, 'boolean': 'false' }) }}
```

or

```
{{ path('route_1', {'id': item.id, 'boolean': 1 }) }}
```

You also should specify the requirements for the argument, in that case I can sent anything.

Anyway, you should pass always text-representable variables like numeric types or text.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="{{ path('route_1', {'id': item.id, 'boolean': 'false' }) }}">Link</a>
```